# Converting a text document with special format to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with the following format:

```
1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700, 
10: space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258, 
4: celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345
```

I need to covert this text to a DataFrame with the following format:

```
Id   Term    weight
1    frack   0.733
1    shale   0.700
10   space   0.645
10   station 0.327
10   nasa    0.258
4    celebr  0.262
4    bahar   0.345
```

How I can do it?

Comment: I can only think of regex helping here.

Comment: Depending on how large/long your file is, you can loop through the file without pandas to format it properly first.

Comment: It can be done with explode and split

Comment: Also , When you read the text to pandas what is the format of the df ?

Comment: The data is in text format.

Comment: What version of python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an optimized way to parse the file with `re`, first taking the ID and then parsing the data tuples.  This takes advantage of the fact that **file objects are iterable**.  When you iterate over an open file, you get the individual lines as strings, from which you can extract the meaningful data elements.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

SEP_RE = re.compile(r":\s+")
DATA_RE = re.compile(r"(?P<term>[a-z]+)\s+(?P<weight>\d+\.\d+)", re.I)


def parse(filepath: str):
    def _parse(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            for line in f:
                id, rest = SEP_RE.split(line, maxsplit=1)
                for match in DATA_RE.finditer(rest):
                    yield [int(id), match["term"], float(match["weight"])]
    return list(_parse(filepath))
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(parse("/Users/bradsolomon/Downloads/doc.txt"),
...                   columns=["Id", "Term", "weight"])
>>> 
>>> df
   Id     Term  weight
0   1    frack   0.733
1   1    shale   0.700
2  10    space   0.645
3  10  station   0.327
4  10     nasa   0.258
5   4   celebr   0.262
6   4    bahar   0.345

>>> df.dtypes
Id          int64
Term       object
weight    float64
dtype: object
```

---

#### Walkthrough

`SEP_RE` looks for an initial separator: a literal `:` followed by one or more spaces.  It uses `maxsplit=1` to stop once the first split is found.  Granted, this assumes your data is **strictly formatted**: that the format of your entire dataset consistently follows the example format laid out in your question.

After that, `DATA_RE.finditer()` deals with each (*term, weight*) pair extraxted from `rest`.  The string `rest` itself will look like `frack 0.733, shale 0.700,`.  `.finditer()` gives you multiple `match` objects, where you can use `["key"]` notation to access the element from a given [*named capture group*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), such as `(?P<term>[a-z]+)`.

An easy way to visualize this is to use an example `line` from your file as a string:

```
>>> line = "1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700,\n"
>>> SEP_RE.split(line, maxsplit=1)
['1', 'frack 0.733, shale 0.700,\n']
```

Now you have the initial ID and rest of the components, which you can unpack into two identifiers.

```
>>> id, rest = SEP_RE.split(line, maxsplit=1)
>>> it = DATA_RE.finditer(rest)
>>> match = next(it)
>>> match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='frack 0.733'>
>>> match["term"]
'frack'
>>> match["weight"]
'0.733'
```

The better way to visualize it is with [`pdb`](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/).  Give it a try if you dare ;)

#### Disclaimer

This is one of those questions that demands a particular type of solution that may not generalize well if you ease up restrictions on your data format.

For instance, it assumes that each each `Term` can only take upper or lowercase ASCII letters, nothing else.  If you have other Unicode characters as identifiers, you would want to look into other `re` characters such as `\w`.

Comment: Brilliant answer, I must say.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DataFrame constructor if you massage your input to the appropriate format. Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

text="""1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700, 
10: space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258, 
4: celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345 """

df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        chain.from_iterable(
            map(lambda z: (y[0], *z.strip().split()), y[1].split(",")) for y in 
            map(lambda x: x.strip(" ,").split(":"), text.splitlines())
        )
    ), 
    columns=["Id", "Term", "weight"]
)

print(df)
#  Id     Term weight
#0  4    frack  0.733
#1  4    shale  0.700
#2  4    space  0.645
#3  4  station  0.327
#4  4     nasa  0.258
#5  4   celebr  0.262
#6  4    bahar  0.345
```

**Explanation**

I assume that you've read your file into the string `text`. The first thing you want to do is strip leading/trailing commas and whitespace before splitting on `:`

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(" ,").split(":"), text.splitlines())))
#[['1', ' frack 0.733, shale 0.700'], 
# ['10', ' space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258'], 
# ['4', ' celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345']]
```

The next step is to split on the comma to separate the values, and assign the `Id` to each set of values:

```
print(
    [
        list(map(lambda z: (y[0], *z.strip().split()), y[1].split(","))) for y in 
        map(lambda x: x.strip(" ,").split(":"), text.splitlines())
    ]
)
#[[('1', 'frack', '0.733'), ('1', 'shale', '0.700')],
# [('10', 'space', '0.645'),
#  ('10', 'station', '0.327'),
#  ('10', 'nasa', '0.258')],
# [('4', 'celebr', '0.262'), ('4', 'bahar', '0.345')]]
```

Finally, we use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten this output, which can then be passed straight to the DataFrame constructor.

**Note**: The `*` tuple unpacking is a python 3 feature.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data (`csv` file) looks like given:

```
df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt', sep=': ', header=None)
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

# split the `,`
df = df[1].str.strip().str.split(',', expand=True)

#    0             1              2           3
#--  ------------  -------------  ----------  ---
# 1  frack 0.733   shale 0.700
#10  space 0.645   station 0.327  nasa 0.258
# 4  celebr 0.262  bahar 0.345

# stack and drop empty
df = df.stack()
df = df[~df.eq('')]

# split ' '
df = df.str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True)

# edit to give final expected output:

# rename index and columns for reset_index
df.index.names = ['Id', 'to_drop']
df.columns = ['Term', 'weight']

# final df
final_df  = df.reset_index().drop('to_drop', axis=1)
```

Comment: how do you not getting error by '''  sep=': ' ''' which is 2 character separator?

Comment: @Rebin add `engine='python'`

Comment: @pault weird, 'cause I already split by `' '`. It yields correct data on my computer.

Comment: @QuangHoang I copied and pasted  your code from scratch and now the output looks good. +1

Comment: @Rebin add it as a param to `pd.read_csv` - `df = pd.read_csv(..., engine='python')`

Answer (score 3):

Just to put my two cents in: you could write yourself a parser and feed the result into `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

file = """
1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700, 
10: space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258, 
4: celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345 
"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    expr    = (garbage / line)+

    line    = id colon pair*
    pair    = term ws weight sep? ws?
    garbage = ws+

    id      = ~"\d+"
    colon   = ws? ":" ws?
    sep     = ws? "," ws?

    term    = ~"[a-zA-Z]+"
    weight  = ~"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"

    ws      = ~"\s+"
    """
)

tree = grammar.parse(file)

class PandasVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_pair(self, node, visited_children):
        term, _, weight, *_ = visited_children
        return (term.text, weight.text)

    def visit_line(self, node, visited_children):
        id, _, pairs = visited_children
        return [(id.text, *pair) for pair in pairs]

    def visit_garbage(self, node, visited_children):
        return None

    def visit_expr(self, node, visited_children):
        return [item
                for lst in visited_children
                for sublst in lst if sublst
                for item in sublst]

pv = PandasVisitor()
out = pv.visit(tree)

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=["Id", "Term", "weight"])
print(df)
```

This yields

```
   Id     Term weight
0   1    frack  0.733
1   1    shale  0.700
2  10    space  0.645
3  10  station  0.327
4  10     nasa  0.258
5   4   celebr  0.262
6   4    bahar  0.345
```

Here, we are building a grammar with the possible information: either a line or whitespace. The `line` is built of an id (e.g. `1`), followed a colon (`:`), whitespace and `pair`s of `term` and `weight` evtl. followed by a `sep`arator.

Afterwards, we need a `NodeVisitor` class to actually do sth. with the retrieved ast.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to just use entirely pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(u"""1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700, 
10: space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258, 
4: celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345 """), sep=":", header=None)

#df:
    0                                          1
0   1                 frack 0.733, shale 0.700, 
1  10   space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258, 
2   4                 celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345
```

Turn the column `1` into a list and then expand:

```
df[1] = df[1].str.split(",", expand=False)

dfs = []
for idx, rows in df.iterrows():
    print(rows)
    dfslice = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [rows[0]]*len(rows[1]), "terms": rows[1]})
    dfs.append(dfslice)
newdf = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# this creates newdf:
   Id           terms
0   1     frack 0.733
1   1     shale 0.700
2   1                
3  10     space 0.645
4  10   station 0.327
5  10      nasa 0.258
6  10                
7   4    celebr 0.262
8   4    bahar 0.345
```

Now we need to str split the last line and drop empties:

```
newdf["terms"] = newdf["terms"].str.strip()
newdf = newdf.join(newdf["terms"].str.split(" ", expand=True))
newdf.columns = ["Id", "terms", "Term", "Weights"]
newdf = newdf.drop("terms", axis=1).dropna()
```

Resulting newdf:

```
   Id     Term Weights
0   1    frack   0.733
1   1    shale   0.700
3  10    space   0.645
4  10  station   0.327
5  10     nasa   0.258
7   4   celebr   0.262
8   4    bahar   0.345
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take for your question. Creating a list which will contain lists for every id and term. And then produce the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
file=r"give_your_path".replace('\\', '/')
my_list_of_lists=[]#creating an empty list which will contain lists of [Id Term  Weight]
with open(file,"r+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():#looping every line
        my_id=[line.split(":")[0]]#storing the Id in order to use it in every term
        for term in [s.strip().split(" ") for s in line[line.find(":")+1:].split(",")[:-1]]:
            my_list_of_lists.append(my_id+term)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_list_of_lists)#turning the lists to dataframe
df.columns=["Id","Term","weight"]#giving columns their names
```

Answer (score 0):

Could I assume that there is just 1 space before 'TERM'?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Term','Weight'])
with open('C:/random/d1','r') as readObject:
    for line in readObject:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        tempList1=line.split(':')
        tempList2=tempList1[1]
        tempList2=tempList2.rstrip(',')
        tempList2=tempList2.split(',')
        for item in tempList2:
            e=item.split(' ')
            tempRow=[tempList1[0], e[0],e[1]]
            df.loc[len(df)]=tempRow
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be easy to understand what there happens. You only need to update the code to read a file instead of using the variable.

```
import pandas as pd

txt = """1: frack 0.733, shale 0.700,
10: space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258,
4: celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345"""

data = []
for line in txt.splitlines():
    key, values = line.split(':')
    for elements in values.split(','):
        if elements:
            term, weight = elements.split()
            data.append({'Id': key, 'Term': term, 'Weight': weight})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

DF:

```
   Id    Term  Weight
0   1    frack  0.733
1   1    shale  0.700
2  10    space  0.645
3  10  station  0.327
4  10     nasa  0.258
5   4   celebr  0.262
6   4    bahar  0.345
```

Answer (score -3):

1) You can read row by row.

2) Then you can separate by ':' for your index and ',' for the values

1)

```
with open('path/filename.txt','r') as filename:
   content = filename.readlines()
```

2)
content = [x.split(':') for x in content]

This will give you the following result:

```
content =[
    ['1','frack 0.733, shale 0.700,'],
    ['10', 'space 0.645, station 0.327, nasa 0.258,'],
    ['4','celebr 0.262, bahar 0.345 ']]
```

Comment: Your result is not the result asked for in the question.